# how to update/delete a record in hudi table in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue, apache-hudi

I have a requirement to update or delete a record the hudi table, one way is to do that with pyspark/scala by following the steps mentioned in the below guide

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hudi-work-with-dataset.html
Also is it possible to do that with aws-cli?

Which one could be better to do this? by calling it through lamda or Glue .

Answer (score 1):

You can use aws-cli to submit spark jobs with EMR steps or notebooks to do adhoc analysis. Submitting spark jobs to EMR is preferred approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used a similar approach. Developed a Glue job with pyspark code and then used the aws-cli commands to trigger the job from git.